# laravel 5 Class implements Iterator

Tags: php, class, interface, laravel-5, iterator

I am trying to integrate an existing library into Laravel5 which itself is not namespaced and uses its own classes in subfolders using require.
I have placed it at 'app/API/libname/mainlibclass.php'.
with sibling directory at 'app/API/libname/toolkit' which contains the classes the library uses.

Calling from a Laravel controller I am unable to create the class using a require statement (correct?) before

```
$objectinstance=new Mainlibclass();
```

so in the main Laravel app I have

```
use app/API/libname/Mainlibclass
```

then later the usual

```
$objectinstance=new Mainlibclass();
```

In the existing library and each of its own used classes I set

```
namespace app/API/libname
```

and 'use' where needed.
I now have no class not found but one of the files uses 'implements Iterator' - I am getting error Interface 'App\API\libname\Iterator' not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `\` in front of that so it looks like this:

```
class ABC implements \Iterator {
```

**Edit**:

I think it would be better practice to keep external non-`psr-4/0` libraries untouched (for easier update if needed in future) and outside of `app/` directory.

You could use [composer classmap autoload feature](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) for this.

Comment: I had tried that preiously with use \Iterator; and got the same - the class is then not found

Comment: Your link was not the best for my situation but you got me on the right trail, hence accepting it for the answer. Plus your ideal of not changing anything in the original code was my intention from the start - its not a library I maintain. Therefore I added into composer the path, did composer dump-autoload and ready to go after a few own code corrections. The original is completely intact and I have a wrapper to it from Laravel5. Thank you

Comment: PS no need now for the '\Iterator' this approach also does not need require - to recap there was a main library class - I classmapped the folder and now its as if its a PHP generic class